# ¿Alguien sabe cómo estructurar una regla con listas en Prolog?

Tags: lista, prolog

Estoy manejando programación lógica con Prolog y tengo la siguiente base de conocimiento y no tengo idea como estructurar una regla para que me extraiga estos datos:

1. Definir una regla que nos diga cuantos documentos fueron prestado de una categoría.
2. Definir una regla que nos diga cuantos documentos fueron prestados de un autor.

La base de conocimiento es la siguiente:

```
% categoria(nombre, numero).
categoria(tecnologia, 2).
categoria(historia, 3).
categoria(geografia, 4).
categoria(matematicas, 5).
categoria(ctesis, 6).
categoria(otros, 7).
categoria(novelas, 8).
categoria(musica, 9).
categoria(cuentos, 1).

% se maneja un functor documento que posee lo siguiente
% libro(titulo, autor, editorial, anio).
documento(libro(aliciaEnElPaisDeLasMaravillas, losHermanosGrim, trillas, 1952), cuentos, 1).
documento(libro(lasCronicasDeNarnia, patricia, elDorado, 2000), cuentos, 2).
documento(libro(donQuijoteDeLaMancha, alfredoAguilar, trillas, 1925), historia, 3).
documento(libro(laNahuala, erikaHernandez, salamancaDc, 2006), cuentos, 3).

% prestamo(noPres, usuario, [documento1, documento2, ... documentoN], fecha(d, mes, anio)).

prestamo(1, selenaGomez, [libro(aliciaEnElPaisDeLasMaravillas, losHermanosGrim, trillas, 1952)], fecha(12, 7, 2017)).
prestamo(2, zaynMalik, [libro(theWitness, katyPerry, capitol, 2017)], fecha(13, 7, 2017)).
```

Si tienen algun libro que me puedan recomendar mucho mejor. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, tienes que pensar que lo primero es tu base de datos, debes hallar la forma de **poner los datos de manera que se relacionen pero no se repitan** en la medida de lo posible, primeramente yo usaría el número de la categoria para relacionarlo, de esa manera podrías incluso poner texto en el valor de la categoría, pero haciendo uso del número como una clave para evitar problemas de comparación y evitar problemas de desempeño.

```
% categoria(nombre, numero).
categoria(tecnologia, 2).
categoria(historia, 3).
categoria(geografia, 4).
categoria(matematicas, 5).
categoria(ctesis, 6).
categoria(otros, 7).
categoria(novelas, 8).
categoria(musica, 9).
categoria(cuentos, 1).
```

Para libro lo pondría aparte en vez de estar dentro de prestamo

```
% se maneja un functor documento que posee lo siguiente
% libro(titulo, autor, editorial, anio).
libro(aliciaEnElPaisDeLasMaravillas, losHermanosGrim, trillas, 1952).
libro(lasCronicasDeNarnia, patricia, elDorado, 2000).
libro(donQuijoteDeLaMancha, alfredoAguilar, trillas, 1925).
libro(laNahuala, erikaHernandez, salamancaDc, 2006).
libro(theWitness, katyPerry, capitol, 2017).
```

Pondría documento con sus referencias a un único campo de los demás datos.

```
%documento(Titulo,No.Categoria,Existencia).
documento(aliciaEnElPaisDeLasMaravillas, 1, 1).
documento(lasCronicasDeNarnia, 1, 2).
documento(donQuijoteDeLaMancha, 3, 3).
documento(laNahuala, 1, 3).
```

Para prestamo reusaría tu regla

```
% prestamo(noPres, usuario, [documento1, documento2, ... documentoN], fecha(d, mes, anio)).

prestamo(1, selenaGomez, [aliciaEnElPaisDeLasMaravillas], fecha(12, 7, 2017)).
prestamo(2, zaynMalik, [theWitness], fecha(13, 7, 2017)).
```

Y finalmente para las reglas, o el programa en sí usaría esas reglas para obtener las relaciones que sean importantes para mí, como por ejemplo:

```
prestamos_por_persona(Persona,Titulos):- prestamo(_,Persona,Titulos,_).
```

Para saber que títulos tiene que persona, sean o no documentos impresos.

```
prestamos_de_documentos_por_persona(Persona,Titulos):- Titulos=[_|UnTitulo], prestamo(_,Persona,Titulos,_),documento(UnTitulo,_,_).

prestamos_de_documentos_por_persona(Persona,Titulos):- Titulos=[OtroTitulo|_], prestamo(_,Persona,Titulos,_),documento(OtroTitulo,_,_).
```

Para saber que títulos de documentos impresos tiene prestados una persona en particular. Tal vez esta regla sea un poco más complicada, pero recuerda que todas las listas en prolog se componen de `[Cabeza|Cola]`, por ello con un predicado allí nos aseguramos de declararlo para buscar con los contenidos y no tratar de obtener coincidencias por toda la lista.

Y finalmente:

```
categorias_de_prestamos_por_persona(Persona,Categoria):- Titulos=[_|UnTitulo], prestamo(_,Persona,Titulos,_), documento(UnTitulo,Numero,_), categoria(Categoria,Numero).

categorias_de_prestamos_por_persona(Persona,Categoria):- Titulos=[UnTitulo|_], prestamo(_,Persona,Titulos,_), documento(UnTitulo,Numero,_), categoria(Categoria,Numero).
```

Para saber el nombre de las categorías de los libros prestados que alguien se ha llevado.

Te dejo la liga de [un buen libro](https://homepage.cs.uri.edu/faculty/hamel/courses/2015/spring2015/csc481/lecture-notes/ln481-012.pdf) que me hallé que seguramente te será de utilidad para el manejo de listas.